# clustering a data set, which one is the best choice

Tags: cluster-analysis

I want to cluster a data set, but I do not know how many kinds in this data set, which clustering algorithm is better? Can someone give me some suggestions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no free lunch**. And no "*best*" clustering algorithm.

Cluster analysis is an explorative technique. There are multiple correct answers, and it is up to you to decide which is most *useful* to you.